# What's the meaning of "people are walked out" phrase?

Tags: phrase-meaning

From: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/44409/826

> There is a very good reason ***people are walked out*** when they are fired or laid off.

What does that mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*To walk* [someone to a place] means to escort or accompany them to that place; to walk with them.

In this case, if you've just fired a man from his job, it's a good idea to have someone walk with him to his desk while he gathers his belongings, and then walk with him to the exit, to make sure that he doesn't steal or damage anything on his way out.

Comment: Sorry, it's an old question, but worth noting that there's a nuance: the emphasis here is on *escort* not *accompany* -- if A "accompanies" B, then B is taking the lead in where they go. If A "escorts" B, then A determines where they are both going. And in this case, it is the security guard who basically says, "Right, now we are going to your desk" (escorts him there) "... and now we are going to the front desk ..." (escorts him there) "...and now we are exiting the building. And now we are outside. Goodbye."